# What does the 9/11 bill mean for foreign governments?

Tags: united-states, international, constitutional-law

Congress is about to pass a 9/11 that would allow families of 9/11 victims to sue the Saudi Government. Does this open a 'Pandora's box' where other foreign governments like Iraq, Afghanistan, Syria, etc..can sue the US government? Very interesting bill.

Answer (score 2):

Not as much as some people seem to think. [28 USC 1605](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1605) already allows suing foreign governments, so this isn't violating some huge legal taboo. Libya was successfully sued over Pan Am Flight 103. The [new bill](https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/senate-bill/2040/text) extends the existing right in some way (I don't have the sitzfleisch to distill out the difference at the moment).

Comment: I guess I should've been more clear. I am not referring to foreign governments suing one another but rather a civilian(person not in government position) suing a foreign government

Comment: The existing law was used by civilians, e.g. the cases of Letelier, Liu, and Pan Am Flight 103, so in that respect there is no change.